# How to interpret or narrow down the cause of a memory leak in this visual leak detector output?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

How do I narrow down the cause to find the reason for the memory leak reported in this Visual Leak Detector output?

The question is not to debug this particular code for me, but how to approach problems like this in general. Visual Leak Detector reports many leaks and questions like this are quite frequent here on SO therefore I hope for an answer which is less specific but more general such that it is not only help in this particular case but more for others as well.

```
---------- Block 305 at 0x00000000FCBFBBB0: 64 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0x7DAD966C, Count: 1, Total 64 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 11728):
  ucrtbased.dll!malloc()
e:\programme (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0 (901): Shady.exe!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_List_node<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::unique_ptr<Texture,std::default_delete<Texture> > >,void * __ptr64> > >::allocate()
e:\programme (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\list (730): Shady.exe!std::_List_alloc<std::_List_base_types<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::unique_ptr<Texture,std::default_delete<Texture> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,st() + 0x19 bytes
e:\programme (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\list (716): Shady.exe!std::_List_alloc<std::_List_base_types<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::unique_ptr<Texture,std::default_delete<Texture> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,st()
e:\programme (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\list (631): Shady.exe!std::_List_alloc<std::_List_base_types<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::unique_ptr<Texture,std::default_delete<Texture> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,st() + 0xC bytes
e:\programme (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\list (818): Shady.exe!std::_List_buy<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::unique_ptr<Texture,std::default_delete<Texture> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > con()
e:\programme (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\list (896): Shady.exe!std::list<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,std::unique_ptr<Texture,std::default_delete<Texture> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,s()
e:\programme (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xhash (197): Shady.exe!std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::unique_ptr<Texture,std::default_delete<Texture> >,std::_Uhash_compare<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::hash<std() + 0x1A bytes
e:\programme (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\unordered_map (119): Shady.exe!std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::unique_ptr<Texture,std::default_delete<Texture> >,std::hash<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::equal_to<std::basic_string()
e:\repositories\shady\src\texture\texturemanager.h (39): Shady.exe!TextureManager::TextureManager() + 0x44 bytes
e:\repositories\shady\src\engine.h (53): Shady.exe!Engine::Engine() + 0x65 bytes
e:\repositories\shady\src\engine.cpp (97): Shady.exe!main() + 0x1D bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl (75): Shady.exe!invoke_main()
f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl (264): Shady.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() + 0x5 bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl (309): Shady.exe!__scrt_common_main()
f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_main.cpp (17): Shady.exe!mainCRTStartup()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk() + 0x22 bytes
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x34 bytes
  Data:
B0 BB BF FC    B4 01 00 00    B0 BB BF FC    B4 01 00 00     ........ ........
CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
```

`engine.cpp 97` is `Engine engine = Engine();` which constructs an object of this class

```
class Engine{
    Engine() : _logger("Engine"){}
    TextureManager _textureManager;
    Logger mutable _logger;
};
```

while `texturemanager.h 39` is `TextureManager() :_logger("TextureManager"){};` of this class:

```
class TextureManager{
TextureManager() :_logger("TextureManager"){};
~TextureManager() {
    for (const auto& kv : _textures) {
        GLuint h = kv.second->getTextureHandle();
        glDeleteTextures(1, &h);
    }
}
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Texture>> _textures;
Logger mutable _logger;
};
```

Did I understand the output correctly that the unordered_map causes the leak? There is no direct allocation with `new` or `malloc` involved in this code as I try to completly move to `shared` and `unique pointers`. Could the string passed to the constructors and reused and stored in the classes the problem? From what I read std::string does manage its memory itself.

Comment: Do you by any chance have an `unordered_map` in your logger? And if so, how does that get cleaned up?

Comment: No but the TextureManager above has an unordered map. I do not cleanup the unordered_map itself as I expect it to be cleaned up properly or am I wrong?

Comment: Assuming your `TextureManager` itself is destroyed (which presumably happens when `Engine` is destroyed, then the `unordered_map` should also get cleaned up.

Comment: Which compiler / STL are you using? It might be worth creating a simple program which has a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<char>>` which you populate with a few entries and then exit, such as http://ideone.com/a3hIaj

Comment: I tried this kfsone and it does not leak. I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

One common problem with memory leak detection is that a memory leak is essentially nothing else than not freed memory at the time the detector analyzes the snapshot.

It looks like the most common false-positive memory leak warnings are static or global variables which are not freed at the time the memory leak dump is created, but will be freed at a later moment.

This makes finding actual leaks more tedious and difficult if you aren't very profound with why some code leaks in the first place. The tool of choice might report a leak where there is none, but you might not understand why.

The first things to check for any reported memory leaks are

- Is a static/global variables involved?

  - Is it necessary to handle them at all or will they be cleaned up properly when the context is released?
- Are containers properly cleaned up?
- Is inheritance involved?

  - If instances of sub classes are stored in pointers of a any base class, do all base classes contain proper virtual destructors?
- Is memory allocated with `new`, `malloc`or similar?

  - Is this memory cleaned up with `delete`, `delete[]` or `free` or similar?

Similar to the [Comment Out Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)#Debugging)-technique it is possible to use memory snapshots to narrow down where memory is leaked. The following example is for Visual Studio but the very same idea can be used with any functionality which allows for memory snapshotting.

```
//Create 3 Memory states, where s3 is the difference
_CrtMemState s1, s2, s3;
//Snapshot the first time
_CrtMemCheckpoint(&s1);
//your questionable code
//Snapshot the second time
_CrtMemCheckpoint(&s2);
//If there is a difference between both states, there is a memory leak
if _CrtMemDifference(&s3, &s1, &s2)
    _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&s3);
```

This idea can be wrapped into a combination of macros and a class to allow for proper context utilization. Combined with the `#ifdef _DEBUG` method to only include the code for a `DEBUG` build you can leave your memory leak detection in your code without performance loss as those macros will be replaced with `no-op` for a `non-DEBUG` build and those should be optimized out by any modern compiler.

Wrapped in macros and a class along with a stack this can be used as follows:

```
#include <MemoryLeakDetector.h>
void foo() {
    BEGINMEMORYLEAKCHECK();
    int * j = new int;
    ENDMEMORYLEAKCHECK();/*Leak 2 of 4 bytes detected.*/
}
int main(void)  {
    /*Because we  use a global stack we can nest our macro use!*/
    BEGINMEMORYLEAKCHECK();
    BEGINMEMORYLEAKCHECK();
    int * i = new int;
    ENDMEMORYLEAKCHECK();/*Leak 1 of 4 bytes detected.*/
    delete i;/*Leak 1 is closed.*/
    foo();/*but we generate a leak 2 of 4 bytes inside of foo*/
    ENDMEMORYLEAKCHECK();/*Leak 2 of 4 bytes is detected here as well*/
}
```

With the following `MemoryLeakDetector.h` which uses a `std::stack` of `std::unique_ptr<MemoryLeakDetector>` to properly handle the different stack contexts. This allows for nested use of our macros. We use `std::unique_ptr` to not only avoid leaks in our `MemoryLeakDetector` code but also to allow us to utilize `std::move` instead of copying the objects.

`MemoryLeakDetector.h`:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef _DEBUG
    //#include <vld.h> /* Visual Leak Detector Memory Leak Detection*/
    #include <crtdbg.h> /*VS Memory Leak Detection*/
    #include <stack>
    #include <memory>
    #include <sstream>
    #include "Windows.h"

class MemoryLeakDetector {
public:
    MemoryLeakDetector() {};
    _CrtMemState MEMORYLEAKSTATISTICS1;
    _CrtMemState MEMORYLEAKSTATISTICS2;
    _CrtMemState MEMORYLEAKSTATISTICS3;
    static std::stack<std::unique_ptr<MemoryLeakDetector>>& stack() {
        static std::stack<std::unique_ptr<MemoryLeakDetector>> s;
        return s;
    }
};


#define DBOUT( s )                              \
do{                                         \
   std::ostringstream os;                   \
   os << s;                                 \
   OutputDebugString(os.str().c_str() );    \
}while(0)

#define BEGINMEMORYLEAKCHECK() do{std::unique_ptr<MemoryLeakDetector> ___memoryleakdetector___ = std::make_unique<MemoryLeakDetector>();\
                                MemoryLeakDetector::stack().push(std::move(___memoryleakdetector___));\
                                _CrtMemCheckpoint(&MemoryLeakDetector::stack().top().get()->MEMORYLEAKSTATISTICS1);\
                                }while(0)           
#define ENDMEMORYLEAKCHECK() do{if(MemoryLeakDetector::stack().size()==0){DBOUT("\n"<<__FILE__<<"("<<__LINE__<<"):"<<"<"<<__FUNCTION__<<" ENDMEMORYLEAKCHECK without BEGINMEMORYLEAKCHECK detected\n");\
                            break;}\
                            std::unique_ptr<MemoryLeakDetector> ___memoryleakdetector___ = std::move(MemoryLeakDetector::stack().top());MemoryLeakDetector::stack().pop();\
                            _CrtMemCheckpoint(&___memoryleakdetector___->MEMORYLEAKSTATISTICS2);\
                            if (_CrtMemDifference(&___memoryleakdetector___->MEMORYLEAKSTATISTICS3, &___memoryleakdetector___->MEMORYLEAKSTATISTICS1, &___memoryleakdetector___->MEMORYLEAKSTATISTICS2)){\
                            DBOUT("\n"<<__FILE__<<"("<<__LINE__<<"):"<<"<"<<__FUNCTION__<<"> MLD detected a leak\n");\
                            _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&___memoryleakdetector___->MEMORYLEAKSTATISTICS3);\
                            DBOUT("\n\n");\
                            std::cerr << "MLD Leak detected "<<__FILE__<<"("<<__LINE__<<")"<< std::endl;\
                            }}while(0)
#else
    #define BEGINMEMORYLEAKCHECK() do{}while(0)
    #define ENDMEMORYLEAKCHECK() do{}while(0)
    #define DBOUT( s )  do{}while(0)
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I narrow down the cause to find the reason for the memory leak

It's possible that you've stumbled on a memory leak in the STL implementation used by your compiler. The best way to narrow this down is to eliminate as many culprits as possible and build an SSCCE or MVCE that does nothing but use the guilty-seeming `unordered_map`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<std::string>> uomap;  //1

    uomap["hello"] = std::make_unique<std::string>("world");  //2

    return uomap.size() - 1;
}
```

http://ideone.com/a3hIaj

Start the program with your leak detector and determine whether you still see the leak or not. If you do, congratulations on your bug find, you'll want to report the bug to your STL vendor.

Incidentally, if you are using Microsoft's implementation, you may find it interesting to note that the construction of an `unordered_map` involves a number of mallocs. You can verify this by setting breakpoints on the lines marked `//1` and `//2` and starting the program.

When breakpoint #1 hits, select Debug -> New Breakpoint -> Function Breakpoint and set a breakpoint on 'malloc'. Now press F5 - if you want to see the stack traces inside the STL/CRT check the "Microsoft Symbol Servers" box and click OK.

You'll find that there are 3-4 calls to malloc just in the construction of the `unordered_map`.